# Change the file if any process or port not accessible - Linux

Tags: linux, mysql

I have a config file where mysql DB details(hostname,port,password,user) are mentioned. I have setup master-master replication on mysql and now i want to setup failover from application side(Nodejs) which contains single hostname as part or connectionstring. Is there a way i can monitor the port(3306) of primary DB and if it is not accessible it should change the config file replacing with other hostname(secondary) to achieve high availability

Thanks,

Comment: What if 3306 is open but INSERTs don't work on it? A normal situation when a filesystem is full.

Comment: Actually all i need to replace the file with different hostname(or ip) where another instance(replica) of mysql is running. Moreover disk space is not an issue, we do have enough space and disk space monitoring is also in place.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has its own [middleware / load balancer thing called MySQL Router](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-using-router.html). The advantage over a layer 4 load balancer is awareness of primary and secondary instances.

Or, there is the option of manually moving it over, such as changing DNS to point to the desired host. Not automatic, but simple.

As with any HA install, the chosen solution should be tested to understand its behavior during failures.

Comment: There's also the use of floating IPs via ctdb or keepalived. HAproxy can also be used to provide floating IPs. HAproxy can be configured to have some visibility into the nature of a MySQL host, but that work has already been done in MySQL Router.